# How can I modify a state config before using it in the config phase of Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to be able to modify the object I provide the stateHelperProvider.state(obj).

I have a module like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .config(stateConfig);

    stateConfig.$inject = ['stateConfigObject', 'stateHelperProvider', 'someProvider'];
    function stateConfig(stateConfigObject, stateHelperProvider, someProvider) {

        someProvider.$get().getSomeData().then(function(response) {
             // use the response here to modify the stateConfigObject
        });
        stateHelperProvider.state(stateConfigObject);
    }
})();
```

Done that way, there will be an a-sync issue and the stateConfigObject will not be the correct one passed into the stateHelperProvider in the end. The config phase will probably finish before the a-sync stuff finishes.  So, is there anyway to make this all happen synchronously?

I've tried using the stateHelperProvider inside someProvider.$get() like so, but still no luck:

```
someProvider.$get().getSomeData().then(function(response) {
   // use the response here to modify the stateConfigObject
   stateHelperProvider.state(stateConfigObject);
});
```